# Viable alternatives to lignin and cellulose for cell walls and wood?

Tags: xenobiology, flora, biochemistry

I want to design alien plants in which wood and cell walls are not made of the lignin/cellulose mixture wood and plant cell walls on Earth are made from, but I don't actually know what materials would be suitable. On it's own, I admit, this isn't a very helpful thing to say, as what counts as "suitable" could be almost infinitely variable, so I have a list of criteria for my definition of suitability:

1. Its strongest form must have a ratio of compressive strength to weight at least 75% that of average Earth wood
2. It should be sufficiently rigid that tall trees made of it would remain upright
3. It should be composed entirely of carbon, hydrogen, oxygen, and nitrogen, with no other elements as part of its core chemical structure
4. It should not be so reactive that it would be significantly more unstable than flammable wood in an oxygen-rich atmosphere
5. It should be possible to biodegrade but not so easy to digest that it cannot form fossil fuels; If it cannot biodegrade at all, it is not viable for use by living things, but I would also like the planet these plants to inhabit to experience an industrial revolution at some point, which requires at least coal, so it must be plausible for it to take long enough for biodegradation of it to evolve that something like what happened in the Earth Carboniferous era could take place whereby it could trap enough carbon before biodegradation evolved that large amounts of carbon-rich material derived from it could be fossilized

With all that out of the way, what materials meet the above criteria and, therefore, could comprise the wood and plant cell walls of an alien world, and what interesting uniquenesses do these have?

Comment: Organic chemistry is infinitely malleable. You are asking for a crash course in the chemistry of polymers. There are entire libraries dedicated to the topic. Cellulose and lignin are not special in any other way than they are made by plants. *It so happened* that plants stumbled upon those two. For example, what is wrong with [polyethylene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyethylene) instead of cellulose and some sort of [polycarbonate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycarbonate) instead of lignin? (And what is biodegradable depends on what has evolved to eat it.)

Comment: Why, please?

Why not adapt known species a little?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The space of possible structural chemicals, as AlexP observed, is Quite Big.

Cellulose is a [polysaccharide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysaccharide), for example. [Chitin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chitin) is another, and is used for the cell walls of fungi. You don't have any cell walls, but various bits of you are held together or held up by [polypeptides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peptide) like [collagen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collagen) or [keratin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keratin). Various things can synthesize [silk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silk), another protein based material.

And terrestrial life's building blocks don't even end there... [lignin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lignin) is a different kind of polymer again (a [polyphenol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphenol)). For a non-polymer example, corals use calcium carbonate, though that's perhaps a little less convenient above the water's surface and not quite so suitable for a fuel, but other minerals could substitute. Styrene, the monomer from which polystyrene is formed, can be [extracted from the resin of a particular species of tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polystyrene#History). Latex rubber is a natural product, and although  is isn't used as a natural structural material it clearly *could* be.

And that's barely scratching the surface of structural compounds. There's plenty of carbon in all those things (apart from maybe conventional corals), and so plenty of scope for forming fossil fuels given enough time and suitable conditions.

The point is you can handwave in pretty much anything you like, given your relaxed and plausible requirements. You're not asking for supernatural properties, so you can just declare your material to exist and you can't really be "wrong". There's no need to go into any detail... just make up a name. It'll be fine. This isn't like inventing a new element, or natural superconductor, or nuclear fuel or whatever. Don't overthink it, and use your limited and valuable brainwidth on other parts of your story and setting.

> It should be possible to biodegrade but not so easy to digest that it cannot form fossil fuels

Lignin was obviously undigestible for quite some time, hence coal, but under the right conditions all sorts of organic matter can turn into fossil fuels. The precursors to oil and gas would have been very much digestible under normal circumstances, but dead stuff sinking to the bottom of an anoxic abyssal plain isn't going to be broken down in the same way as the same material sitting around in a damp, temperate, oxygenated location. Wood free plant matter can form peat, and peat can turn into coal too; its about the environment of decay as much as the materials involved.

Remember also the existence of [nylonase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nylon-eating_bacteria)! Just because something might seem unbiodegradeable *now*, does not mean it is intrinsically immune to all forms of digestion.

> an industrial revolution at some point, which requires at least coal

It isn't a fundamental requirement, merely a very convenient thing to use. Oil and gas are more awkward to work with, but they can do all the necessary things.

That said, there's nothing to stop you using your authorial fiat to say that your xenolignoid polymers can undergo coalification (which is a real word, apparently).

Comment: And black mould either always had or has evolved the ability to eat Silicone. Even silicone laced with fungicide!

Comment: Already pretty exhaustive answer, but I would mention the cell wall of Bacteria made of peptidoglycans. Don't know what macroscopic properties it would have. But yes, it's just another polymer of glucids and peptides.

Answer (score 8):

**Chitin or Keratin**

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chitin):

> Chitin $(C_8H_{13}O_5N)$ is a primary component of cell walls in fungi, the exoskeletons of arthropods such as crustaceans and insects, and the radulae, cephalopod beaks and gladii of molluscs. It is also synthesised by at least some fish and lissamphibians.[1] The structure of chitin is comparable to cellulose, forming crystalline nanofibrils or whiskers. It is functionally comparable to the protein keratin.

Chitin is structurally similar to cellulose and suitable for uses ranging from cell walls to shells to exoskeletons, and presumably everything in between. It would work for tree bark too.

Answer (score 2):

**Polycarbonate.**

[image: polycarbonate]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycarbonate#Construction_materials

[image: lexan]

[lexan sheets](https://www.indiamart.com/proddetail/polycarbonate-sheet-thickness-3mm-23752508873.html)

There are many types of plastic.  Above is polycarbonate; the stuff is strong, light and durable.  There are other kinds of plastic.  Probably you are sitting on some.  You are!  And that button on your pants is plastic.  You can leave it buttoned for now.

Plastic I am reminded sometimes has nonorganic interlopers but polycarbonate is just C H and O.  There is no reason biology could not make it.  It would be easier than making diamonds which was my initial idea.  I like the idea of Gaudiesque organic plastic structures comprising the plants of your world.  In a world of plastic plants there would of course eventually evolve things that could eat the carbon in the plastic.  Our world is not quite there yet, and so plastic accumulates the way cellulose did before fungi evolved the ability to eat it.

---

Skeptical Mark.  Luckily I have a love of learning!

> Its strongest form must have a ratio of compressive strength to weight
> at least 75% that of average Earth wood

[Polycarbonate properties](https://www.azom.com/properties.aspx?ArticleID=2008)
Compressive Strength    121- 159 MPa    17.5496 - 23.061    ksi
1 ksi = 1000 psi.  23.061 ksi = 23061 psi.

[Southern red oak wood](https://www.matweb.com/search/DataSheet.aspx?MatGUID=ea505704d8d343f2800de42db7b16de8&ckck=1)
Compressive Strength    3.79 MPa    550 psi Green, perpendicular to grain
6.00 MPa    870 psi 12% moisture content, perpendicular to grain
20.9 MPa    3030 psi    Green, parallel to grain
42.0 MPa    6090 psi    12% moisture content, parallel to grain

Oak = 0.52g/cc  compressive strength / weight = 11711

[Polycarbonate = 1.22g/cc](https://www.jiga.io/calculator/density/polycarbonate/gml)
compressive strength / weight  = 18902

Polycarbonate has a little less than 400% of the compressive strength of the strongest oak.  Compressive strength / weight exceeds oak.

> It should be sufficiently rigid that tall trees made of it would
> remain upright

I think this has more to do with the 3dimensional structure of the trunk than the stiffness of the material.  But for your viewing pleasure here is a polycarbonate dome measuring about 3m.

https://vikingdome.com/en-be/products/auradome-60-standard-geodesic-dome

[image: dome]

> It should be composed entirely of carbon, hydrogen, oxygen, and
> nitrogen, with no other elements as part of its core chemical
> structure

Yes but no nitrogen.  You can add your own when you are done with it, if no-one is watching.  This is supposed to be a tree after all.

> It should not be so reactive that it would be significantly more
> unstable than flammable wood in an oxygen-rich atmosphere
> Yes.
>
> It should be possible to biodegrade but not so easy to digest that it
> cannot form fossil fuels

Yes.  They are just carbon carbon bonds.  No funky halogens to make the molecule indigestible.  In an oxygen atmosphere they would provide good energy.

Comment: Plastic is...a rather broad category, and not all plastics meet the requirements of the question.  For example, a tree made from polylactic acid would tend to sag over time, one made from nitrocellulose would make eucalyptus look fire-safe, and one made from polytetrafluoroethylene incorporates elements other than C, H, O, N.

Comment: @Mark would you replace your downvote with a shimmering upvote if I chamge the title to Polycarbonate?  I would not need to change much else since that is the molecule shown and product shown. I am ready to do that in exchange for the sweet Mark upvote…

Comment: If you explain why polycarbonate meets the requirements in the question, I'll change to an upvote.  I don't think it meets the strength requirement, though: it's got a strength-to-weight ratio of around 60 kN\*m/kg, where wood starts around 120 kN\*m/kg.

Comment: @Mark - there you go.

Comment: Well, that's one way to get the strength-to-weight ratio: compare it to oak, rather than to pine or spruce.